# Difference between "중국어" and "한자어"

Tags: meaning, sino-korean-words

중국어 - Chinese language
한자 - Chinese characters
한자어 - Sino-Korean language(???)

Comment: 중국어 — the Chinese language / 한자 — The Chinese characters / 한자어 — Sino-Korean _**words**_. 語 (어) means a language or a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

한자어(漢字語) in the Korean language simply indicates a group of words based on Chinese characters or words, as opposed to 고유어(固有語) or 순우리말, both point to the other group of native-oriented words.

Here, the words "고유어" and "순우리말" are synonyms, but the word "고유어" is a 한자어, while the word "순우리말" is a 고유어.

And of course, not every word either has Chinese-origin or is native-oriented. Thus there's the third group, 외래어(外來語), for the words *imported* from the rest of the world.

Comment: “고유어 is a 한자어?” No, it isn’t. What did you intend to say?

Comment: 고유어(固有語) is a word that all of its letters are Chinese characters. It is a 한자어.

Comment: Wait, hold on... Did you mean the word "고유어" itself is a Sino-Korean word? I find the way you phrased it a bit misleading...

Comment: Let me clarify that one. With "The word," we could make clear that you're talking about the words themselves, not their meanings.

Comment: Just like monosyllabic is multisyllabic. :P

Comment: Well, that was intentional, and was supposed to be the fun part. Now you took all the fun out xD